# How to show a variable value in jasper report title?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a jasper report, want to show the value of a column returned through last record of my query, in the title band. Kindly help to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

To get the last value of your record, if this is what you are after, set the `evaluationTime` of your `textField` from the Title Band to `Report`.

The text field expression, in this case, is going to be evaluated when the end of the report is reached, thus producing the last value from your result set for a particular `field`.

The JRXML fragment might look like this:

```
<title>
  <band height="100">
    <textField evaluationTime="Report">
      <reportElement x="72" y="16" width="100" height="24" uuid="698866c8-7d26-4bc7-8727-b4a56d239a53"/>
      <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MyField}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    ...
  </band>
</title>
```